# Deploying web role in Azure throws exception on CurrentAccountStorageName

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-web-roles, powershell-cmdlet

I want to deploy a web role to Azure using the PowerShell CmdLets.

My script is as follows:

```
$subscription = "<name-of-subscription>"
$service = "<name-of-cloudservice>"
$slot = "staging"
$package = "path\to\package.cspkg"
$configuration = path\to\config.cscfg"
$deploymentLabel = "Deploy to $service"

Import-Module "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Azure\PowerShell\Azure\Azure.psd1"
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "C:\path-to.publishsettings"
Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccount $service -SubscriptionName $subscription

# some more stuff to check whether to upgrade or to create ...

Set-AzureDeployment -Upgrade -Slot $slot -Package $package -Configuration $configuration -label $deploymentLabel -ServiceName $service -Force
```

When I execute this it throws an error:

```
Exception: The subscription named <name-of-subscription> already exists.
```

I figured that since I'm importing my publishsettings-file already I could get rid of `Set-AzureSubscription`. However, once I do that I get the next error:

```
Exception: CurrentStorageAccountName is not set. 
Use Set-AzureSubscription subname -CurrentStorageAccountName storageaccount to set it.
```

This is the line that gave me the error in the first place, so I'm not sure how I need to set the storageaccountname without causing an error.

I also ran a little test:

```
Import-AzurePublishSettingsFile "C:\path-to.publishsettings"

Get-AzureSubscription | Format-Table
```

Once I do this I get the following output (reformatted):

```
SubscriptionName:        <name-of-subscription>
SubscriptionId:          123456789-123...
ServiceEndpoint:         https://man....
ActiveDirectoryEndpoint:  
ActiveDirectoryTenantId:
IsDefault:               True 
Certificate              [Subject]
CurrentStorageAccountName 
CurrentCloudStorageAccount 
ActiveDirectoryUserId
```

As you can see, the `CurrentStorageAccountName` is empty, but I don't know how I can set it to a correct value.

I looked up some other scripts, but they all seem to be having this sequence of importing, then setting. Any idea why this is not working and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out the reason. It appears that you cannot include the subscription name as a named parameter. Changing this line:

```
Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccount $service -SubscriptionName $subscription
```

to this line did the trick

```
Set-AzureSubscription $subscription -CurrentStorageAccount $service
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to set CurrentStorageAccount to the name of your cloudservice, but you should be setting it to the name of your blob storage account. Get the list of you storage accounts

```
PS U:\>Get-AzureStorageAccount |select StorageAccountName 

StorageAccountName
------------------
portalvhdsgsomething
storage1
storage2
storage3
```

then run your previously failing line but with the name of your storage account ie.

```
Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccount storage2 -SubscriptionName $subscription
```

You can confirm your changes with

```
PS U:\>Get-AzureSubscription | select CurrentStorageAccount

CurrentStorageAccount      : storage2
```

Comment: Tried that as well, but to no avail

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which part fails and what is the error?

Comment: The same as before: `Exception: The subscription named <name-of-subscription> already exists.`

Comment: Hmm.. try   

`Select-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscription` before running   


`Set-AzureSubscription`   

Do you get an error then?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use -CurrentStorageAccountName as the parameter of Set-AzureSubscription.

Comment: That is what I have: `Set-AzureSubscription -CurrentStorageAccount $service -SubscriptionName $subscription`

Answer (score 0):

For `Set-AzureSubscription` the MSDN doc shows the `-SubscriptionName` parameter as parameter 1, not as named. The error message's suggested fix even implied that you needed to do `Set-AzureSubscription <service> -CurrentStorageAccount <storage solution>` Perhaps simply moving that will solve it?

```
Set-AzureSubscription -SubscriptionName $subscription -CurrentStorageAccount $service
```

Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn495189.aspx

Comment: I tried that as well, but the order doesn't seem to matter

Comment: Where exactly in your script is it throwing the error?

Comment: When I don't do `Set-AzureSubscription` upon executing `Set-AzureDeployment`, otherwise on `Set-AzureSubscription`

Comment: Only other thing I can think of is that you have a different subscription as your 'current subscription' apart from what's in $subscription, perhaps it is defined as part of your file import? Try doing a `get-azuresubscription | set-azuresubscription -currentstorageaccountname $service` and see if that clears it up. If it does you may have conflicting subscription references. I'm out for the night, I'll see if I come up with any better ideas and check back tomorrow.

Comment: No, when I do a Get-AzureSubscription it only shows that one, with an empty CurrentStorageAccount. Thanks for the help! Good night.